# Yii2 - Save form in modal with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, ajaxform, pjax

I have two models one is "register-products" (where I have a dropdown with all brands) and another form is "brands". I need to render form "brands" inside the form "register-products" to create a new brand using bootstrap `Modal` widow and it works, but I need the newly created brand to be available inside the dropdown of the `register-products` form so that I don't have to refresh the page each time.

At this moment what happens is that after creating a new brand is redirecting to the view with details of the new brand.

**register-products form**

```
<?php
 Modal::begin([
     'header' => 'Test',
     'id' => 'modal',
     'size' => 'modal-lg',
 ]);
      echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
 Modal::end();
 ?>

Html::a('+', ['/brands/create'], ['id' => 'open_modal', 'class' => 'btn btn-success']);
```

**js**

```
$(function(){
$('#open_modal').click(function (){
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
      $('#modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').html(data)
   });
   return false;
});
```

**BrandsController**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Brands();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } elseif (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add the code for the `register-products`, what are you using for the dropdown , select2 or any other and the reason for the page being redirected is that you are not submitting the form `brands` via ajax, as there is no `beforeSubmit` event code that you have inside the view that would prevent the normal form submission and post every thing using `ajax`

Comment: thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam It's the `beforeSubmit` I need. I researched and found this tutorial that helped me and to solve my problem. Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhblqEROLWo&t=384s&list=LLIzd7cUG_PQ6ZjEvxNE8nuw&index=2